# Computer boots with no display, hitting enter restarts computer?

Tags: windows-8, boot, display, reboot, post

As per thread title.
I'm unable to diagnose the issue since I cannot get a visual output on my monitor.
The fans and components seems to boot up normally.

However, I've noticed that if i hit enter on my keyboard, the computer flickers (fan lights) for a bit and goes through the whole boot up sequence again (noted through the dual seven segment display on the motherboard).

The motherboard is a Z77 Extreme 4 asrock motherboard with a 7950 GPU connected.

I have tried both onboard and dedicated graphic using all 3 cable types (dvi,vga and hdmi).

Furthermore the parts in questions are not new. These parts were in a working computer but taken out to be placed a new casing. The only added components are fans and a ssd.

There are no beeps. The motherboard did initially note that the RAM were not in place. I have adjusted that and the error code has disappeared.

Any advice on what might have gone wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Update : I have isolated the issue to the GPU. The system boots up fine without the GPU. However if the GPU is inserted neither the onboard nor the gpu display works.

Comment: Is this a custom build or a pre-built?  Has it ever worked or is this a problem from the start?  What are the specs?  A few details will really help us be able to help you!

Comment: Any Beep sounds? Remove the monitor cable and check for "No Signal" output in the monitor and isolate whether it is an issue with monitor or system. If monitor works just fine, check the VGA cable and the Display adapter properly.

Comment: Hi, I appended the question. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the CMOS?  Usually there is a jumper.  If not disconnect the power cord, remove the CMOS battery and hold the power button for 30 seconds.  Then allow the motherboard to sit for about 5-10 minutes.  Put the battery back in and power up.  That should reset the CMOS.  Also remove any attached devices like the SSD, other drives, any PCI cards, etc and only boot the moboard, CPU and RAM (with fans of course)

Comment: @MikeNaylor. Hi I have isolated the issue to the GPU. The system boots up fine without the GPU. However if the GPU is inserted neither the onboard nor the gpu display works.

Comment: @MikeNaylor Update 2 : The system works now. Changed PCIE slots on the GPU. Much appreciated.

Comment: sounds like that PCIE slot is bad, I'd recommend a new board or if you're really brave reflow the solder on the PCIE connectors if this is a test or 'junk' system.